# Triggering an action at a certain time, is it possible?

Tags: iphone, timing

I am just looking into development for the iPhone and I was wondering if it is possible to trigger an action at a certain time?

Based on what I have read it does not seem like this is currently not an option because there are no background processes allowed. Is this true? If so do you guys/gals have any ideas on alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is not running, then no, it's not currently possible.

If your app is running, you can always use `NSTimer`.

Also, a manual trigger method was mentioned here on SO that involves sending emails with links in them that cause your app to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this article about [Push Notification Service: Apple's Solution to run iPhone Apps in the background](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2008/08/push-notificatn.html), which may be of help.